# Exporting Form Data to Google Calendar - TypeError: cal.createEvent is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create calendar events from a Google Form. I get the following runtime error

> TypeError: cal.createEvent is not a function (line 42, file "Code").

My current code is as follows.

```
function createEvent() {
    var form = FormApp.openById('1Y2FnxrX_Z40qkva57Bt_NjYCfhZWciig-wWxbgmGwOM');
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Paws Appointment Sample');
    var responses = form.getResponses();
    var len = responses.length;
    var last = len -1 ;
    var items = responses[last].getItemResponses();
    var email = responses[last].getRespondentEmail();
    var type = items[0].getResponse();
    var date = items[1].getResponse();
    var time1 = items[2].getResponse();
    var time2 = items[3].getResponse();
    var time3 = items[4].getResponse();
    var time4 = items[5].getResponse();
    var time5 = items[6].getResponse();
    var time6 = items[7].getResponse();
    var time7 = items[8].getResponse();
    var startTime = time1+time2+time3+time4+time5+time6+time7;
    var animalName = items[9].getResponse();
    var animalNumber = items[10].getResponse();
    var fosterName = items[12].getResponse();
    var subject = "Foster Walk-In Visit: "+animalName;
    var url = 'https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=f16mtjblk9ttjhka4pfou8673c%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York';
    var body = "You can view your scheduled visit here "+url;
    var replace = date.replace(/-/g,"/");
    Logger.log(replace);
    var start = new Date(replace);
    Logger.log('start '+start);
   //Logger.log(newStart.getHours());
    var endHours = 0+30+start.getHours();


    Logger.log(start.getDay());
    var day = start.getDate();
    var minutes = start.getMinutes();
    var year = start.getFullYear();
    var month = start.getMonth();
    var hours = start.getHours();

    var d = new Date(year, month, day, endHours, minutes);
    Logger.log(d);
    var event = cal.createEvent(animalName+' '+animalNumber+' Foster Walk-In Visit',start,d);
    addGuest(email);
    setDescription(fosterName);

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject , body );

}
```

How do I resolve the above error?

Answer (score 0):

`cal` object in your code is defined by `CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(...)` which returns [an array of `Calendar` objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#methods). So most likely, first you need to check whether the array is not empty (such calendar exists), and after that access it by its index (eg. `cal[0].createEvent(...)`)

Comment: I changed the first line and got this error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' (line 1, file "Code.gs"). I changed it the other way by removing cal at the end and it looks like it is running but the execution log keeps repeating and it says start is invalid. Can you assist me with my dates and times?

Comment: @RandeeFrankel it seems I did not properly check the code, so I my previous answer is invalid. I'll fix it now.